# Sybase SQL : Use of Condition operator in IF and CASE statement

Tags: c#, sql, database, sybase

I want to use Greater than and less than operator within IF and CASE statement but its not working. I unable to found out any solution.
What I want to do is if TotalPurchases are greater than 10 than replace all values with 0 otherwise replace all values with q

```
Select  pur_mst.n_srno, act_mst.c_code, act_mst.c_name , 
sum (pur_mst.n_subtotal)TotalPurchases,
            ( CASE TotalPurchases 
            WHEN TotalPurchases > 10
            THEN TotalPurchases = 0
            ELSE TotalPurchases  = 20 ) as type
            from act_mst join pur_mst ON
            act_mst.c_code = pur_mst.c_supp_code  
            Group by pur_mst.n_srno,
            act_mst.c_code, act_mst.c_name
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN TotalPurchases > 10 THEN 0 ELSE 20 END`. `CASE WHEN` expression always should return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting the syntax for Case when

```
 Select  pur_mst.n_srno, act_mst.c_code, act_mst.c_name , 
        CASE 
        WHEN sum (pur_mst.n_subtotal) > 10 THEN  0
        ELSE  20 End as TotalPurchases
        from act_mst join pur_mst ON
        act_mst.c_code = pur_mst.c_supp_code  
        Group by pur_mst.n_srno,
        act_mst.c_code, act_mst.c_name
```

Comment: This query create a new column as named type. I need to modify values of TotalPurchases. Those are still same. :(

Comment: Select pur_det.c_batch_no,  pur_det.c_item_code , Query1.n_srno, Query1.c_code, Query1.c_name , Query1.TotalPurchases,
   (pur_det.n_pur_rate) PurRate, (pur_det.n_sale_rate) SaleRate
   from pur_det join
   
    ( Select  pur_mst.n_srno, act_mst.c_code, act_mst.c_name , 
    ( CASE 
    WHEN sum (pur_mst.n_subtotal) > 10
    THEN  0
    ELSE  20 END ) as TotalPurchases

    from act_mst join pur_mst ON
    act_mst.c_code = pur_mst.c_supp_code  

    Group by pur_mst.n_srno, act_mst.c_code, act_mst.c_name

Comment: Got it now. Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: Please upvote or mark it as answer,if it has helped you.